# Pre-Commit throwing Errors on Missing whitespace after ":"

Tags: python-3.x, pre-commit, flake8, pre-commit.com

I used the same pre-commit configuration on my windows pc, but since i switched to a macos, whenever i run a pre-commit on my python-django project, i get unexpected errors like missing whitespace after colon, even when the said colon iS at the end of a class definition or function definition or colons present in a url string, i know from the docs that a space is not needed after this cases, i believe this has something to do with the os switch or some misconfiguration with pre-commit on my new pc,

***Python VERSION: 3.12***

**pre-commit configuration**

```bash
exclude: "^docs/|/migrations/"
default_stages: [commit]

repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks:
      - id: trailing-whitespace
      - id: end-of-file-fixer
      # - id: check-yaml

  - repo: https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade
    rev: v3.3.1
    hooks:
      - id: pyupgrade
        args: [--py310-plus]

  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.12.0
    hooks:
      - id: black

  - repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/isort
    rev: 5.12.0
    hooks:
      - id: isort

  - repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
    rev: 6.0.0
    hooks:
      - id: flake8
        args: ["--config=setup.cfg"]
        additional_dependencies: [flake8-isort]

# sets up .pre-commit-ci.yaml to ensure pre-commit dependencies stay up to date
ci:
  autoupdate_schedule: weekly
  skip: []
  submodules: false
```

**Sample Error Message**

```
config/settings/production.py:109:21: E231 missing whitespace after ':'
```

**Acutal line pointed at in the code**

```py
STATIC_URL = f"https://{aws_s3_domain}/{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}/payment/static/"
```

Can anyone help and is there a work around to this, i can disable this check in the pre-commit yaml file (which is counter-intuitive, cause i am using this checks to ensure my codebase is consistent), but again this was working fine on my windows pc, so i am trying to find an actual solution and not a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using flake8 6.0 which does not support python 3.12 -- this support was added in flake8 6.1

you either need to do one or the other of these:

- upgrade flake8 to 6.1 (usually via `pre-commit autoupdate`)
- force an older python version via `language_version: python#.#`

---

disclaimer: I maintain flake8 and I wrote pre-commit

Comment: I feel like i am in the presence of a god! Thank you very much for this and all you do for me and couple million people through your contributions 